# jQuery dataTable plugin. How to reduce number of server roundtrips when user types in search box?

Tags: jquery, datatable

The title pretty much asks the question. I am using the dataTable plugin in a page. although I initially thought the search-as-you-type feature was cool, it has quickly become a pain in the rear end, as it unnecessarily starts sending requests to the server when a user starts typing. I want to restrict this to say only send request to server when we have N or more chars typed in the search box.

I have not found a way to do this yet?. Does anyone know how to do this?

**[Edit]**

A typical code snippet showing use of dataTable to dynamically fetch data from the server is given below:

```
  $('#elem_id').dataTable({
    'bProcessing': true,
    'bServerSide': true,
    'oLanguage': {
        'sLengthMenu': 'Show <select>'+
        '<option value="25" selected="true">25</option>'+
        '<option value="50">50</option>'+
        '<option value="100">100</option>'+
        '</select> entries'
    },
    'sAjaxSource': "/getdata"
 });
```

As can be seen from the snippet, there is no (obvious?) way of trapping the keystrokes from the search box in the page - am I missing something?

I used the following code (selector correctly identifies the 'search box'), but it did not work:

```
$('#elem_id_filter > :input[type="text"]').change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Clicked');
    return false;
});
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to only send a request to the server when the search string has a certain length.

e.x. check client side 'searchstring'.length() > certain value

```
function keystrokeHanlder(){
   var searchstring =  this.text();
   if(searchstring.lenght%5==0)
       ServerRequest(searchstring);
}
```

I'm assuming you have attached the keystrokeHandler to the textbox or whatever you use
to get the searchstring input. It's rather crude but should get the work done.